# on first load no javascript work at all

Tags: jquery, slider, loading, html

I am having strange problem, whenever my site is loaded for the first time in the browser, its jquery and slider doesnt work at all........ then when i refersh the page it loads it properly....
I am using Firefox latest 3.6.8 version
CSS is loaded before jquery and slider scripts

here is the link for website [link text](http://www.gulzarchildcare.com)

**I fixed the button positioning with 2 solutions**

1. One was to use % in positioning like left:90%
2. Other i found by checking the original easy slider 1.5 css file which was to use a container to display all the content within and container will have same width as the images in the slider.....
   hope it helps others

Comment: Works fine for me loading it first time in FireFox, Opera and IE8.

Comment: Agreed, no problems here. Do you get any errors in the Tools->JavaScript Console when it fails?

Comment: Just one side note: IMHO you shouldn't use `+` and `-` as buttons here, as you're not zooming in and out or something. I'd use arrow(like) buttons.

Comment: i think zoom in and out also have some search styled glass thing with it.....it just means increase and decrease....its your own perception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had no difficulty viewing your site in Firefox version '3.6.8' without a refresh? The slider appears to function correctly, however, with fresh eyes I did notice some things in the page source that you might wish to check, especially point 1.:

1. **[EDIT]** The JavaScript block within the 'Head' tag is missing closing semicolons (';') at the end of the first four 'var' lines:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var browser = navigator.appName
       var ver = navigator.appVersion
       var thestart = parseFloat(ver.indexOf("MSIE"))+1
       var brow_ver = parseFloat(ver.substring(thestart+4,thestart+7))
       if ((browser=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") && (brow_ver < 7))
       {
           alert("Please Update your OLD BROWSER ,Please install Google chrome or Firefox to view the site propertly");
           window.location="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/products/download.html";
       }
   </script>
   ```

   **[EDIT]** Also, it's advisable to include JavaScript in 'CDATA' or 'Character Data' sections:

   > ```
   > <script type="text/javascript">
   > //<![CDATA[
   >     // Your Javascript goes here...
   > //]]>
   > </script>
   > ```

   More info: [here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA).

   **[EDIT]** Finally, notice the variable '`brow_ver`' is declared in the script, but on the following line a variable '`browser`' is referenced?
2. The ‘`&amp;`’ character entity reference should be used instead of ‘&’ in the ‘title’ tag
3. One of the 'Meta Tags' is missing a closing '/'.
4. **[EDIT]** The conditional comment '`<![if !(IE 6)]>`' should be '`<!--[if !(IE 6)]>`' **and** '`<![endif]>`' should be '`<![endif]>-->`'
5. **[EDIT]** The UTF-8 encoding includes and encompasses all of US-ASCII characters, so in the meta tag consider using the following 'Content Encoding':

   `content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` instead of `content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"`
6. Also FYI: the '-' and '+' navigation buttons for the slider are not positioning correctly. Please see image reference below. This might not be apparent on your screen... try a higher resolution with the browser set to full screen to replicate it.

   **[EDIT]** Just for others reading this... I notice you have fixed the '-' / '+' navigation positioning by using '%' instead of 'px' in the CSS. So for example:

   ```
   #nextBtn{
       display:block;
       width:36px;
       height:36px;
       position:absolute;
       left:90%;  /* <<< Will position correctly */
       top:365px;
       z-index:1000;
   }
   ```

   instead of...

   ```
   #nextBtn{
       display:block;
       width:36px;
       height:36px;
       position:absolute;
       left:1025px;  /* <<< Won't position correctly */
       top:365px;
       z-index:1000;
   }
   ```

The same goes for the 'Previous' nav button.

[Site Screenshot of incorrect navigation buttons positioning http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8443/gulzarchildcarecom.jpg](http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/8443/gulzarchildcarecom.jpg)

The best of luck with the site... it looks good! :)

Comment: You have pointed out a lot of good errors, but can you tell me that what should i do to position those plus and minus signs..........
they are positioned with absolute and i am using em in their left values like left:78.5em

Comment: Muhammad, I have just added a few edits above that you might wish to check-out. I notice you sorted the positioning problem - well done. Don't forget to fix that JavaScrpt too, as it might cause issues in some browsers. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to wrap JQuerys

```
$(document).ready(function() {
}
```

function arround your slider code.

Sounds to me like your code is only loading fast enough, when its cached after the first page load.